# Dictionary type data sorting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, sorting, data-science

I have this type of data

```
{"id":"colvera","gg_unique_id":"colvera","gg_unique_prospect_account_id":"cobra-hq-enterprises","completeness_score":100,"full_name":"chris olvera","first_name":"chris","last_name":"olvera","linkedin_url":"linkedin.com/in/colvera","linkedin_username":"colvera","facebook_url":null,"twitter_url":null,"email":"colvera@cobrahq.com","mobile_phone":null,"industry":"information technology and services","title":"independent business owner","company_name":"cobra hq enterprises","domain":"cobrahq.com","website":"cobrahq.com","employee_count":"1-10","company_linkedin_url":"linkedin.com/company/cobra-hq-enterprises","company_linkedin_username":"cobra-hq-enterprises","company_location":"raymore, missouri, united states","company_city":"raymore","company_state":"missouri","company_country":"united states"
```

i want to set "**id**","**gg_unique_id**" etc as ****column** name and the values as row**. How can i do that?
Im trying the following codes but nothing happens:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("1k_sample_data.txt")
data.info()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

I am new to this type of data, any help would be appriciated

Comment: Something like `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have data in Json format. Try:

```py
df = pd.read_json("1k_sample_data.txt", lines=True)
print(df)
```